# My Ola Hallengren nightly backup job failed but It works fine when I execute the job manually by right clicking

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, backup, jobs, ola-hallengren

I have been using Ola Hallengreen maintenance plan . It has been working great for longtime  . Recently one of my nightly backup job failed repeatedly with an error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection

I then execute the job manually by right clicking on it and start at step... and it runs fine. No problem.

The server is SQL Server 2008R2.

Does any one know why the job failed?

Comment: staring recently  one of the database refreshed from prod server at the same time. I changed job schedule time. Now it works fine

Comment: Thanks for letting us know that it was a scheduling issue that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to address the problem by increasing the timeout periods.

Increase the standard settings on your server for `remote login timeout (s)` and `remote query timeout (s)`.

Or in your connection string you could include "Connect Timeout=120;General Timeout=120;" to increase the time allowed for the connections.

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection

The error above happened when you try to do something that take time higher than the original timeout. you can try `-l` option to increase the timeout for the command.
example:

```
sqlcmd.exe -U myuser -P mydb -l200 \\fill other needed info
```